# How to find a seg-fault in a pointer to pointer linked list function?

Tags: c

I am creating three functions that enable me to insert into a linked list using pointer to pointer format in different ways. The problem is I am getting a seg fault in one of these functions and gdb is not telling me where they are for some reason. Any suggestions on where they might be?

```
// This is the function where I can insert to the front:
void insertAtHead( List *list, int val )
{
  Node **link = &( list->head );

  Node *n = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  n->value = val;

  n->next = *link;
  list->length++;
}

//This is the function where I can insert at the end.
void insertAtTail( List *list, int val )
{
    Node **link = &( list->head );
    Node *n = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node *temp;


    n->value = val; // Link the data part
    n->next = NULL; 

    temp = *link;

    while(temp->next != NULL)
        temp = temp->next;

    temp->next = n; // Link address part

    list->length++;
}

//This function lets me insert the value by finding the largest value and putting the given value before it.
void insertSorted( List *list, int val )
{
    Node **link = &( list->head );
    Node *n = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node *temp;

    n->value = val; // Link the data part
    n->next = NULL; 
    temp = *link;

    while(temp->next != NULL || val < temp->value)
        temp = temp->next;

    temp->next = n; // Link address part

    list->length++;
}

// Lastly, the main function:
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  FILE *fp;
  if ( argc != 2 || ( fp = fopen( argv[ 1 ], "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
    printf( "Can't open file: %s\n", argv[ 1 ] );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  {

    List list = { NULL, 0 };

    int val;
    while ( fscanf( fp, "%d", &val ) == 1 )
      insertAtHead( &list, val );

    printList( &list );

    freeList( &list );
  }

  fseek( fp, SEEK_SET, 0 );

  {

    List list = { NULL, 0 };

    int val;
    while ( fscanf( fp, "%d", &val ) == 1 )
      insertAtTail( &list, val );

    printList( &list );

    freeList( &list );
  }

  fseek( fp, SEEK_SET, 0 );


  {

    List list = { NULL, 0 };

    int val;
    while ( fscanf( fp, "%d", &val ) == 1 )
      insertSorted( &list, val );

    printList( &list );

    freeList( &list );
  }

  fclose( fp );

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The main function and the rest of the small function I know are correct but the problem seems to be from one of those three functions. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Comment out each line from main and run it and see which one causes the crash if you don't know how to use a debugger. Then do the same thing in the function that is causing the crash comment out and uncomment line by line, then address the issue

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: Hint: you never update the head of the list.

Comment: @dbush In which function?

Comment: @A.A All three.

Comment: @dbush For the first function, I was thinking of putting ```list = n;``` but that doesn't seem to work since list is a struct.

Comment: @dbush I can't seem to figure out how to update the list since there is no head parameter in the function's parameters

Comment: @A.A You pass a pointer to the list, so update `list->head`.

Comment: @dbush For the first function, I did ```*link = n;``` and the program did not give me a seg fault. For the second and third functions, I did ```*link = temp;``` but it gave me a seg fault. What i am doing wrong in the second and third functions?

Comment: @A.A Depends on where you do it.  Step through through the program with a debugger to see what exactly is happening.